# How to pass variable to php without a new window opening?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i have a page where the visitor inputs data into a text area and i want that data to be saved to a file.

All is working fine but when the data is passed to the php script it opens a new window and i don't want that. I want the data to be passed without opening a new window or without the page having to refresh.

My javascript code to pass the data to php:

```
window.open('post.php?' + data, target='_blank');
```

My php script that receives the data and writes it to a file:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to make an Ajax request.

Comment: @ snwflk don't know what you mean? It's all working fine, the data is passed and saved to txt file but i just don't want a new window to be opened.

Comment: You literally call `window.open` although you don’t want a window to open. You'll need to replace that call with something different..

Comment: @ snwflk exactly.... that's what i am looking for but so far i did not find anything

Comment: You could create a form around your textarea and simply submit the form towards your PHP script. This does reload the page but does not open a new window.

Comment: @Dennis that is no option for me since the data passed to the textarea comes from javascript and there is no user submit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do it with ajax:

```js
       $.get("post.php?" + data, function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
```

P.S: Remember to include jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```js
     $(function(){
       $.get("post.php?" + data, function(data){
           
       });
    });
```

This worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Found my answer:

```
window.open('post.php?' + data, target='_blank').close();
```

This closes the window after opening it.

Comment: A popup is not the correct way of doing that. Window.open can be blocked by some browsers (since it is a popup). You need to use ajax for your operation (it is quite simple to use, google it).

Comment: @Cosmin Staicu your right but the problem is i don't know anything about ajax... any example script?